# Linux cannot detect windows partitions

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Parrot OS 4.0 on my PC. It already has Windows 10 on it. I want to use both as a dual boot PC. My HDD is 1TB & it has 4 partitions in Windows. But when I in installation screen i can't see those partitions. I can only see the whole HDD as a single partition.

About a week ago, i had parrot 3.9 in same hdd as a dual boot, i used a "EasyBcd" tool in windows to clean linux partition without losing win grub. I don't know if this tool caused the issue, because i tried to install parrot in an External Hdd, and debian can see ALL ExHDD partitions without any problems !

How can i fix this please?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please add the `sudo fdisk -l` output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Parrot OS on your drive with the Windows partitions, boot into Windows, delete the partition where you want to install Parrot OS and leave it as unallocated space, and then install Parrot OS. The unallocated space will then be available for installation.